# How should resources in a compiled jar be accessed?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, processing, embedded-resource

First of all, I have read through many S.O. questions regarding this topic and I have tried the things suggested in them.

Here is my situation. I am writing a Java app using the Processing framework and I'm in the final stages where I need to begin thinking about packaging the app. A jar file that is executable from the command line is what I'm attempting to build using the Export feature in Eclipse.

The structure of my project looks like this:

```
src/
   multiple packages/
libs/
   jar files and natives
data/
   fonts and images
config/
   json files
```

When I export the jar file and uzip the jar to inspect it's contents, I find that the contents of these dirs have been dumped in the top level of the .jar.

Which looks like this:

```
.jar
    packages
    jar files
    fonts
    json files
```

So, when I attempt to load a config file with something like:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( path ) );
```

Everything works just file when I run the app in Eclipse. But the jar file throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Many of the questions that I've seen on S.O. regarding problems like these recommend using using `class.getClass().getResource()` or `class.getResourceAsStream()`. I have tried both of these using relative paths and just the file name as in:

```
class.getResource( 'config.json' );
class.getResources( 'cfg/config.json' );
class.getResourceAsStream( '../../config.json' );
```

All of these methods return null, when run from either Eclipse or the jar using:

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

I am also open to using an Ant file. In fact, I'm now using the Ant file generated by the export feature to build the jar. If there is something I can add to that to add the directories into the jar that would be great too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reach resources in the root, prepend a `/` to the path.  If not, you do it relative to the current package, which is usually only useful if the resource is physically next to the class in your sources too.

So use `class.getResourceAsStream("/config.json");` to reach config.json in the root of the jar.

Also note that jars-inside-jars are not directly supported.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you suggesting that I use the forward slash in a addition to getResource()?

Comment: This seems to get much closer. This is the path that this returns: 
jar:file:/C:/path_to_project/myjarfile.jar!/config.json However, when I run the jar I still get a file not exception even though the path is correct. I should also mention that it does work from within Eclipse.

Comment: You cannot use FileReaders with resources inside jars.  You must use the InputStream returned from getResourceAsSTream.

Comment: Ah, great! I'll give it a go.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working using the forward slash and an InputStream.

Comment: Good question, good answer.  See also the [info. page on embedded-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Answer (score 2):

Your .jar file should just include the directories related to the "package" for the compiled code.  You might be referencing a .war structure with /lib /WEB-INF  etc. and this is different.

If your package structure is:

```
 com.yourco.authentication
```

And your class in Login

Then your jar should be

```
/com/
  /yourco/
    /authentication/
        Login.class
```

you then need the .jar in your classpath for the env to run via command line.

I see you note it works in Eclipse which likely has environment settings and imported required libs, etc. so hard to tell exactly.  If your packages/ folder includes the compiled java code, I'm unsure if that'll work when referenced externally, thus suggesting you start your packages in the root folder.

Comment: I see other suggestion with editing your code to reference /.  without testing, it could work but it looks like you're trying to package an app and not a lib with your directory structure.